# Routing traces of different width onto an IC on a 4-layer PCB in Eagle

Tags: power-electronics, eaglecad, buck-boost

I am finishing my design of my buck/boost converter using LTC3780 IC on a 4-layer PCB.

Those 1mm blue width traces will carry 2-3 amps.

I need a way to connect those traces of the same layer (blue) onto the IC pins.
What I temporarily do to "fix the problem" was connecting it through vias but those vias add unnecessary impedance for a trace that's the same layer as the pin itself.

[image: pcb-board]

Comment: You can right click on any segment of a trace and modify the width, or go to the command line and type `change width <desired width>` and then click on the traces you want to change.

Comment: Btw your current capability for a trace is only as good as it's thinnest part...

Comment: @RonBeyer, not really true.  Ampacity tables assume infinite length, meaning all parts of the wire must deal with their own cooling. A short length of narrow trace connected to wider traces is able to be cooled by heat conduction out its ends, so can handle more current than the standard tables indicate. Of course, working out the actual maximum current requires substantial effort.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, and near the IC it can use the IC as cooling, if these are ground traces, adding via's to a ground plane can help, or the same for power to power plane traces, or you can add localized planes for cooling around the necked-down traces. The OP should try to limit the necked-down size to as small as possible which would help a lot, necking it down and running it 10mm doesn't make a lot of sense from a cooling perspective.

Comment: @RonBeyer, sure, but necking down to 0.25 mm and running it for 1 mm at 2-3 A is probably okay.

Comment: I don't know what your color code is, but it looks to me like your pins are on the red layer and your blue-layer traces run under serveral pins.........

Answer (score 1):

The blue traces are gate drives and you will have not any issues with those.  While they reach 2-3A, that is pulsed and the average current (which translates to trace warming) is pretty low.

Look at the sample layout for the LTC3789 (similar chip) to get some hints on better layout.  I think you are going to have issues with the connection between the low-side switches and the current sense resistor, and possibly the IntVcc bypass cap.

I have done several designs with the LTC3789 and getting good performance from these parts does require reasonably good layout and very careful routing of the high frequency, high di/dt current loop.

You should also be using Kelvin connections around R1 for the current sense, even though the bottom side is ground, you need a separate, isolated trace for the current sense.  The top side of R1 to current sense should not be sampled where it appears to be.

[image]

For the layout, take a look at this:
[image]

The current sense resistor is directly above the BB controller and the ground extends horizontally from the input caps to the low side of the current sense resistor to the output caps.  I have found this layout works best.  If you are running at high currents, use that ground pour to connect the input ground to the system ground (don't use a continuous ground plane, or at least don't connect it on the input side.  This will help maintain a clean system ground.

The layout below is incomplete (my project for today), but you can get a general idea of the layout.  The ground and input/output power planes will be extended (and the sense trace below C18 will be moved to layer 3 or 4).  The sense traces from the current sense resistor (sorry, haven't fixed the silkscreen yet) will be run on layer 4 over to R7 and R8.  The LTC3789 has a second current sense loop I use on the output at R2, you can see how to layout the sense connections there.  This is a battery charger BTW, so the output current limit is handy.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Dean for your answer. Starting from the beginning, should I leave the blue traces connected as the picture or you suggest an improve despite what you comment of the current which i totally agree. Referring to the sense resistor you recommend place it between the low side of the mosfets right?

Comment: The blue traces are ok as-is, I amended my answer with additional info above.  What are your inputs / outputs (voltage / current)?

Comment: thanks so much, i clear understand now. my buck-boost converter has 12v input and 20v output and 4A output current.